# Back Button Implementation in Fragment ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have 3 `Fragments` inside a `ViewPager`. I have different back button functionalities which I want to implement for each `Fragment`. At the moment, I have created methods in each fragment which correspond to what I want the back button to do. I implemented an interface in my activity with the following methiod:

```
@Override
public void onCameraBack(int i) {
    currFrag = i;
}
```

The idea here is that there are three fragments, each fragment calls this method in its `onStart()` method. Fragment 0 passes 0, fragment 1 passes 1 and fragment 2 passes 2. So in this way the holding activity knows which fragment is visible. Now I am trying to get a reference to that fragment to be able to call the backbutton method I have implemented in it. I tried using this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (currFrag == 0) {

    }
    else if (currFrag == 1) {
        FragmentBTesting fragmentBTesting= new FragmentBTesting();
        fragmentBTesting.FragmentBBack();
    }
}`
```

but this doesn't work. I can't use the `findFragmentbyId` method since my fragments do not have fragment tags in their XML, they fill the whole screen and their views are defined using `linearLayouts`. My question is how can I get an instance of the fragment so I can call its `FragmentBack()` method.

Here is my full activity

```
  public class FragmentActivityTesting extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentATesting.logoutListener,FragmentBTesting.onCameraBack {
ViewPager viewPager = null;
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(MyApp.getContext());
int currFrag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_activity_testing);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pic_pager);
    setStatusBarColor();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("CLOSE_ALL");
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

}
@TargetApi(21)
public void setStatusBarColor() {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 21) {
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

    }

}

@Override
public void logout() {
    session.logOut();
    Intent a = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(a);
    Intent intent = new Intent("CLOSE_ALL");
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    finish();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (currFrag == 0) {

    }
    else if (currFrag == 1) {
        FragmentBTesting fragmentBTesting= new FragmentBTesting();
        fragmentBTesting.FragmentBBack();
    }
}


@Override
public void onCameraBack(int i) {
    currFrag = i;
}
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (position ==0) {
        fragment = new FragmentATesting();
    }
    else if (position == 1) {
        fragment = new FragmentBTesting();
    }
    else if (position == 2) {
        fragment = new FragmentCTesting();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of telling your activity what fragment you are currently on, why not tell it what to execute when back is pressed?

In your activity you can have a field to hold the callback field (as a `Runnable`, I know so much hate.  You can make your own interface if you want), the setter, and then the `onBackPressed` implementation.  Here is a snippet from my code that works.  Im using Guava's `Optional` class, but you can `null` it instead if you're into that kinda thing.

This is the Activity which should implement `ActivityWithHomeButton`

```
private Optional<? extends Runnable> backButtonListener = Optional.absent();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Check if there is a custom back button
    if (backButtonListener.isPresent()) {
        backButtonListener.get().run();
        backButtonListener = Optional.absent();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void setBackButtonListener(Optional<? extends Runnable> backButtonListener) {
    this.backButtonListener = backButtonListener;
}
```

Here is the interface I implement in the activity

```
public interface ActivityWithHomeButton {
    void setBackButtonListener(Optional<? extends Runnable> runnable);
}
```

and of course the usage from a fragment

```
parent.setBackButtonListener(Optional.of(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do back button stuff
        }
    }));
```

You can put this wherever you want in the fragment.  You are also going to want to clear the back button listener whenever you no longer need it (`onPause`). You can do this as such

```
parent.setBackButtonListener(Optional.<Runnable>absent());
```

Where `parent` can be attained using the standard activity-fragment communication pattern detailed here (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).  This code goes in your fragment

```
private ActivityWithHomeButton parent;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        parent = (ActivityWithHomeButton) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement ActivityWithHomeButton");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Two questions, does parent refer to the outermost layout? Should I clear the listener in the onDestroy(), onPause() and onDestroyView() methods?

Comment: And is my activity meant to implement ActivitywitHomeButton or my fragment?

Comment: Activity implements ActivityWithHomeButton.  If you need the listener whenever the fragment is shown I believe you would want to clear it in #onPause (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ePcpvCCqKgY/UhODSSrFHoI/AAAAAAAAAoI/D-ARz8gpkUA/w506-h930/android_fragment_lifecycle_complete.png).  Full disclosure: I am no expert on the activity/fragment lifecycle, but this is where I have put it.

Comment: What does the parent refer to?

Comment: Also if activity implements the listener, how can we call setbackbuttonlistener in the fragment, that function won't be defined there right?

Comment: `parent` is the reference to the Activity.  You can use the standard pattern (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).  I will add that code to the example.